# PHP Recursively File Folder Scan Sorted by Modification Date

Tags: php, sorting, recursion, readdir, filemtime

I'm using this script to see all subfolders and files of subfolders

```
   function readfolder($dir)
    {
        global $tfile,$tdir;$i=0;$j=0;$myfiles;
        $myfiles[][] = array();
        if (is_dir($dir)) {
            if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
                while (($file=readdir($dh)) !== false) {
                    if (!is_dir($dir."\\".$file))
                    {
                        $tfile[$i]=$file;
                        $i++;
                        echo $dir."\\".$file." <b>File</b><br>";
                    }
                    else {
                        if (($file != ".") && ($file != "..")) {
                        $tdir[$j]=$file;
                        echo $dir."\\".$file." <b>Directory</b><br>";
                        readfolder($dir."\\".$file);
                        $j++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                closedir($dh);
            }
        }
    }

    readfolder(".");
```

Can someone tell me how can I use filemtime function (or whatever) so that I can sort subflders and files by modification date?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a look at the SPL [DirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php). It's cleaner than what you're currently doing and trivial to make it recursive. It also has a suitable mtime method.

Comment: There's even a recursive directory iterator in the spl, see http://docs.php.net/class.recursivedirectoryiterator

Comment: Thanks @VolkerK — not sure how I missed / didn't remember that. In my defence, it's still early!